# Do noindex tags on subdomain pages affect image indexing?

Tags: seo, subdomain, search-engine-indexing, images, noindex

Maybe stupid question, but I have to ask:

I'm hosting my images on a subdomain. My main site is `example.com` and images are stored on `static.example.com`.

Subdomain is just a simple html page - when you type its address in the browser, a blank page with "access forbidden" will pop up. If I put a `noindex` tag in that page (index.php), will my images stop indexing as well? The html page is called index.php and you can find it in the /media folder (images are stored here as well).

Of course I want to keep indexing my images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your image files themselves are embedded/linked from prominent pages on your main domain and accessible to search engine crawlers, any other pages on either domain (including the "main page" of `static.example.com`) can be `noindex` without affecting the indexability of the rest of your content.

One thing to note is that if your `access forbidden` page serves a 403 status code, don't worry about search engines indexing it because they skip indexing pages that serve 400-series errors anyways.

Comment: My static page does not serve 403 status code, it's just a plain text added by me

Anyways, thank you! That's all what I wanted to know :)

Comment: @kacper3355 If this answered your question fully and completely, please don’t forget to mark it as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Alright, done! :-)